# Who has accessed/opened a file on the network and when?

Tags: permissions, network-shares, windows-server-2008

Pretty simple:

A certain folder with sensitive information was left accessible to users in a organization unit when it should have been private. I have fixed this, but now the department is asking if we can see who on the network, if anyone, has accessed the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you had previously enable auditing, you're out of luck.

Here's a fairly good guide on enabling file and folder auditing:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Auditing_Windows_Server_2008_File_and_Folder_Access